# orgtbl-to-orgtbl removes special header lines

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have a table with some formatting lines in the header, e.g.,

```
#+ORGTBL: SEND DEST orgtbl-to-orgtbl :splice nil :skip 0
| N   | First name | Last name |
| /   |     <      |         < |
| <l> |    <c>     |       <r> |
|-----+------------+-----------|
| 1   |    John    |       Doe |
| 2   | Priscilla  |     Water |
```

If I press C-c twice to activate the radio table, the following shows up at the target:

```
#+ BEGIN RECEIVE ORGTBL DEST
| N | First name | Last name |
|---+------------+-----------|
| 1 | John       | Doe       |
| 2 | Priscilla  | Water     |
#+ END RECEIVE ORGTBL DEST
```

However, I want **all** the header lines, including the column lines and justification! How can I do that? I've looked through the documentation for `orgtbl-to-generic` but have not found (understood) what I should use.

org-mode version: 9.6.6, emacs version 29.1.

Comment: Why do you need that? Can you explain the use case? It seems to me that the table at the destination is going to be formatted by whatever  command applies to the document, so why does it make any difference what it looks like in the buffer?

Comment: @NickD: I export the destination table to latex. Without the / line I get no column lines. Without the <l> lines I cannot have non-default justification.